# Error loading psycopg2 module with virtualenv and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, postgresql, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I’m configuring a Django 1.7 project in a Ubuntu server (v14.04) with Apache, mod_wsgi, Virtualenv and Postgres. After all configurations I have a Internal error, with this log:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2
>   module:
>   /home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so:
>   undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Traceback log error:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=13365): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/domain.com/projectname/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=13365): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/domain.com/projectname/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 23, in <module>
import psycopg2 as Database
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: /home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/domain.com/projectname/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup()
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 40, in <module>
class Permission(models.Model):
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 297, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 166, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 242, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 108, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 27, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: /home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

Apache .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/domain.com/projectname/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/domain.com:/home/ubuntu/VirtualEnvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<Directory /var/www/html/domain.com/projectname>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /var/www/html/domain.com/media/
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/domain.com/static/

<Directory /var/www/html/domain.com/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/domain.com/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Project wsgi file (/var/www/html/domain.com/projectname/wsgi.py):

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/domain.com')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "projectname.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The psycopg2 module has been successfully installed and can access without problems:

```
python
import psycopg2
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Thank you.

Comment: The error hints that the module is somehow compiled against a different Python version than used by Apache mod_wsgi

Comment: Thank you @Mikko. I already had tried to change mod_wsgi to python 2.7 but I didn't get and then I saw somewhere that maybe it would be about the postgres/django. With your answer I tried again change o mod_wsgi to python 2.7 and I got. I saw the solution [here](https://www.fir3net.com/Programming/Python/how-do-i-compile-modwgsi-for-python-27.html)

Done! :)